# Факториал больших чисел JS

Tags: javascript

Делаю задачу связанную с факториалами. Как задачу решить уже придумал, но, к сожалению, реализовать идею получается только на небольших числах, если взять факториал числа 30, то выходит настолько большое число, что оно заменяется на символы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно посчитать факториал числа на JavaScript при этом сохраняя полностью число, без замены цифр на символы. Спасибо!

Код ниже работает на небольших числах:

```
function factorial(num) {
  if (num === 0 || num === 1)
    return 1;
  for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    num *= i;
  }
  return num;
}
factorial(30);
```

Или:

```
function factorial(num) {
    var rval=1;
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        rval = rval * i;
    return rval;
}
factorial(30);
```

Comment: https://github.com/KenanY/big-factorial

Comment: очень желательно без каких-либо библиотек

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bigint

Comment: Но на самом деле вопрос похож на XY-проблему. Так что лучше расскажите какую настоящую задачу вы решаете

Comment: Вы решили мою, проблему ссылкой выше, спасибо огромное!

Comment: необходимо реализовать метод длинной арифметики, он будет более рациональный уже был вопрос почти по вашей теме вопрос, в котором есть подробные ответы звучит как:
"Как вывести большое число как строку в Javascript?"
надеюсь помог

Answer (score -1):

Ответ на мой вопрос здесь: learn.javascript.ru/bigint - необходимо было добавить "n" к каждому суммированному числу, т.e:

```
const sumBigInts = 10000n + 2000000n
```